# JSON response and calling next() in Express

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible, using Express 4, to send a JSON response to the front-end indicating that there was an error, as well as calling next(err) inside the Express middleware, so that the error can be handled by the server as well? Or are these calls completely mutually exclusive?

My current assumption is that you can do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ error : true });
});
```

and you can do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('here goes the error message');
});
```

but that you can't do this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ error : true });
  next(new Error('here goes the error message');
});
```

and you can't do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('here goes the error message');
  res.json({ error : true });
});
```

Comment: Can you include some sample code?

Comment: @kdbanman Like what? It'd look like sending json then calling `next`.

Comment: What do you mean by "so that the error can be handled by the server as well"?

Comment: @DaveNewton  It's a question about function call compatibility, so wouldn't it be better to include code that shows exactly how he wants to use them?  It removes ambiguity.  It makes it easier to help.  It shows that some effort is already invested.  (That's a legit question - you have a lot of rep and meta activity and I don't.)

Comment: I added some code as an example, but if @robertklep is correct, then that would answer the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They aren't mutually exclusive. For example (instead of middleware I'm using route handlers to demonstrate, but the principle is the same for both):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ error : true });
  next(new Error('something happened'));
});

app.get('/another', function(req, res, next) {
  next(new Error('something happened'));
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err);
  if (! res.headersSent) {
    res.send(500);
  }
});
```

You could check `res.headersSent` in the error handler to make sure that a response is sent (if not, the error handler should send one itself).

Comment: cool, let me give that a shot, for the longest time I thought they were exclusive