# How to trigger next() in express Router.route and controller pattern?

Tags: javascript, express

I can't seem to figure out how to implement 'next()' after the request lands to one of my api routes. I want to do logging after everything is done, and not before my api routes. I have implemented the controller pattern on my routing. I can only do logging for now on errors, but I want to do logging on all requests:

```
//------ api/index.js
import routes from './routes/index.route';

app.use('/api', routes);


// ??? HOW TO HANDLE next() called in "/api routes"
// only handles incoming requests not found in "/api routes"
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // logic here...
  next(error);
});


// global error handler
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  // logging logic here...
});



//------ routes/index.route.js
import express from 'express';
import userRoutes from './user.route';
import bookRoutes from './book.route';

const router = express.Router();

router.use('/user', userRoutes);
router.use('/book', bookRoutes);



//------ routes/book.route.js
import express from 'express';
import bookCtrl from './../controllers/book.controller';

const router = express.Router();
router.route('/:bookId').get(bookCtrl.getBook);




//------ controllers/book.controller.js
export const getBook = async (req, res, next) => {
  const book = // get book logic here;

  return res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(book);

  // HOW DO I TRIGGER next()?  
  // I tried this approach as well: 

  // res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(book);
  // next();

  //however, it would say, "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try calling it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to trigger next which is not sending a response immediately instead assigning it to `res.locals` and calling next. Here are the changes based on my above code:

```
//------ api/index.js
// handle next() event coming from "/api routes"
// and also handles incoming requests not found in "/api routes"
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (res.locals.status) {
    const { status, responseData } = res.locals;
    res.status(status).json(responseData);
    // logging logic here...
  } else {
    // error logic here...
    // forward this error into the global error handler
    next(error);
  }
});



// controllers/book.controller.js
export const getBook = async (req, res, next) => {
  // get book logic here..
  const book = // get book logic here;

    res.locals = {
      status: httpStatus.OK,
      responseData: {
        book,
      },
    };

    next();
}
```

Thanks to @destoryer for the res.json tip! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
 return res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(book);
 // HOW DO I TRIGGER next()?
```

with

```
res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(book);
next();
```

And it will work.

Comment: I think he was asking in javascript not jquery

Comment: Also, `return` in the line before should be removed.

Comment: @whoami There's nothing about this answer related to jquery.

Comment: @Jonas W, I tried that already, it would say 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.'. :(

Comment: @Woppi `json()` sends a response to the client. Any middleware coming after it can't possibly send more stuff as the response is already gone. Read the [express guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#response-methods).

Comment: @destoryer woah I didn't know that as some answers here in SO have a solution wherein next is after the res, like this best answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081561/2098493

Comment: @destoryer thanks for the tip, I was able to do something else that would trigger next